# Find the radius of convergence for the power series

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Find the radius of convergence:

a) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1+(1)^)z^n$

b) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1^{-n^2})z^n$

These problems are different from what I encountered before. From what I remember, I use the ratio test. Does this method still apply here?

Comment: If $i=\sqrt{-1},$ as is likely intended, then $1/e^i$ isn’t real, so it can’t be the radius of convergence.

Comment: The Ratio Test involves the absolute value (here, complex modulus) of the coefficients, so the answer will always be a nonnegative real number.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh right, taking the absolute value, it would just be R=1 for both cases. Is this true?

Comment: @GregMartin are they both R=1 when applying modulus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)   $R=\frac{1}{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|e^{in}|^\frac{1}{n}}$ and $|e^{in}|=|\cos n+i\sin n|=1$

b)   $R=\frac{1}{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|e^{-n^2}|^\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}e^{-n}}=\infty$

Comment: For a) do you mean $|e^{i}| = |\cos(1) + i\sin(1)| = 1$

Comment: Yes, use the formula $e^{i \theta}=\cos \theta +i \sin \theta$.

Comment: Since R deals with lim sup, isn't the supremum of $e^{-n}$ equal to 1? so b) would also be R=1?

Comment: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n=s$ iff $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}  s_n=\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}  s_n=s$. You have to decide why supremum of the set $\{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is $1$ and $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{n}=0$. The same logic works here.